# Is there a way my app can have different behavior depending on the device?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want my app to behave differently if it is being used in a touchscreen device (It'll run in the browser). Is there any JavaScript code that allows me to check that?

Answer (score 0):

There are few properties in js which can help you

**ontouchstart** - An event which triggers when touching DOM elements.

**maxTouchPoints** - It's a read only property which returns the maximum number of touch points that device supports
It can be used something like this

```
function isTouchScreen() {
     return ( 'ontouchstart' in window )||( navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0 ) ||
    }
```

isTouchScreen() will return True if it's touch screen.
You can use [react-device-detect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect) if you want to have different functions for different devices if you're looking for this.